# Windows Command Prompt cannot Display Japanese

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal, command-prompt

[image]

No matter how I change the codepage, the command prompt cannot display Japanese. All chars show as rectangle box.

chcp 932 and chcp 65001 both not working.

Comment: Have you tried using Powershell instead of the legacy command prompt?

Comment: @Harry PowerShell works after changing the codepage

Comment: That's probably your best bet in the long run, then.  (You might be able to get the legacy command prompt to work by choosing an appropriate font, but I've never tried.)